# iron-router wait on Collection.findOne() as data object before render

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I am looking for a solution that iron-router is waiting for a successfully find method on my collection before rendering.

My route looks like this:

```
this.route('business', {
        path : '/business/:type/:_id',
        waitOn : function () {
            return Meteor.subscribe('business', this.params._id);
        },
        data : function () {
            return Business.findOne({_id: this.params._id});
        }
    });
```

This works fine. It seems that iron-router is waiting for the subscribe of the Collection to get the right Document back for the client. But the data which i need in my template has a delay for the findOne function.

```
Template.businessItemItem.rendered = function () {
    console.log(Router.current().data()); // undefined
    window.setTimeout(function(){
      console.log(Router.current().data()); // [Object]
    }, 1000);
}
```

**Solution**
For everyone with the same problem. Just add the "action" method for your route like this:

```
action : function () {
   if (this.ready()) this.render();
}
```

With this method everything works fine for me.

Comment: You are my hero! This was driving me crazy. Your solution is perfect, but I'll investigate more: if it's a bug in iron-router we should open an issue on github. Thanks!

Comment: Yes i think it does not work the way it should. reference: https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/dev/DOCS.md#waiting-on-subscriptions-waiton It says that the waitOn method is waiting for the data before rendering and returns it - but this is not what i currently do ...

Comment: A quick update to add that I had a case when data() function was called before (and then after) action() method (if I refresh from the browser causing the route to reload). In this case even this solution isn't working :-( so I switched to `if (!this.ready()) return;` put as the first line of data() method, as suggested in this post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/lK3v9ZxIbco

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I get your problem, but if I do, you should read about [Controlling subscriptions](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router#controlling-subscriptions), and especially `Router.onBeforeAction('loading')` . Now, you're reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but please see my solution i already edited to my question. The action method with this.ready in use works fine :)

Comment: Sure it works, because you are basically recoding the default "loading" hook, which is better because it applies to every route, with your solution, one would have to copy/paste this "action" code on every route.

Comment: I have the same issue. I tried using the waitOn() hook and it seemed to do nothing. I was returning an array of a couple of subscribe() calls, which is supposed to make the route wait, but it did not. Timo's solution worked for me though. Maybe there's a bug the the iron-router.

Comment: @Jachin, You're sure you have the line `Router.onBeforeAction('loading')` in your code?

Comment: Same issue here. @PeppeL-G  I have `Router.onBeforeAction('loading')` in code but it's a different problem. Sure @Timo solution is recoding something that "should" already be there, but in some circumstances it seems not. I'll try to isolate a case and put a repo on github.

Comment: @Jachin - I had the same problem - i fixed it with adding Router.configure {
  loadingTemplate: "loading"
}